# Services and Controller namespacing collition in rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, routes

I have a service that provides communication for an external API, that gets used internally, but I need to add a controller to display such data, these are my files:

```
app/
  controllers/
    blog/
      posts_controller.rb
  services/
    blog.rb
    blog/
      posts.rb
```

The thing is that if I add a route for the **post** resource, the route is being drawn to the *blog.rb* file inside services directory, and not the controller namespace blog. Here are the routes I've tried:

```rb
  namespace :blog do
    resources :posts, controller: 'posts'
  end

  namespace :blog, path :blog do
    resources :posts
  end

  namespace :blog do
    resources :posts, controller: 'blog/posts'
  end
```

The error I am getting is always the same:

```
Unable to autoload constant Blog, expected /app/services/blog.rb to define it
```

My question, is there a way to specify in the routes where to find the controller, not relying on the convention.

Here are the class definitions:

```
#posts_controller.rb
class Blog::PostsController < ApplicationController
...
end

#services/blog/posts.rb
module Blog
  class Posts
  ...
  end
end

#services/blog.rb
module Blog
...
end
```

Comment: Would you please add the class definitions for `blog.rb` and `posts.rb`?

Comment: Have you added services folder to the load_path?

Comment: yes @SzilardMagyar services folder is autoloaded